# Built in lagged operator function in Julia

Tags: arrays, functional-programming, julia

Is there a built-in lagged operator function in julia? I.e., a function of the form:

```
lagop(op,array,offset)
```

that returns something like

```
[array[i + offset] (op) array[i] for i in 1:length(array)-offset]
```

For successive differences, there is the `diff` function. For sums either of the following works:

```
x = collect(1:10)
x[1:end-1]+x[2:end]
[x[i]+x[i+1] for i in 1:length(x)-1]
```

Is there a general function to accomplish tasks like this?

Comment: `lagop(op,array,offset) = [op(array[i + offset], array[i]) for i in 1:length(array)-offset]` is not enough?

Comment: @Liso It's definitely implementable, but in some scenarios these kinds of operations are ubiquitous and such a function saves time/increases readability. E.g., the [`rollapply` function](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/zoo.pdf#Rfn.rollapply.1) in the `R` package `zoo`.

Answer (score 1):

You mention the zoo library in R, which is for time series. If that's your use case, you will find lag implemented in TimeSeries.jl: http://timeseriesjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apply.html#lag It may not be exactly what you want, though.

Comment: Not exactly what I want but this is helpful. It looks like maybe the feature I was looking for is too easily implemented in the base language to deserve its own function...